# Applying Tauberian theorems for Laplace transforms

Tags: fourier-transform

I'm trying to apply the [Tauberian theorems for Laplace transforms](http://www.google.com/search?as_q=tauberian+theorem+laplace+transform):

\begin{align}
f(t)&\simeq t^{\rho-1}L(t)\\
&\Updownarrow\\
f(s)&\simeq \Gamma(\rho)s^{-\rho}L(1/s)
\end{align}

where $0<\rho<\infty$ and $\Gamma(\rho)$ is the Gamma function.

This theorem should be applied to the waiting time PDF with the asymptotic behavior:

\begin{align}
\psi(t)\sim\frac{1}{t\ln^\beta(t)}
\end{align}
where $\beta>1$.

That is I want to calculate $\psi(s)$. But when I try to apply the theorem, I get $\rho=0$, which is not allowed. I don't know if I can make a trick to avoid this?

Comment: This is related to statistical physics. This computation is about a continuous time random walk with the waiting-time PDF given above.